# How do I find path for Messages and WhatsApp messages backup data in iCloud?

Tags: icloud, backup, messages, whatsapp.app

I need to retrieve Messages and WhatsApp messages backup data from iCloud but I can't find the path. Is there any possibilities to find Messages and WhatsApp messages backup data location in iCloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iMessage data is not currently accessible via iCloud. This will be coming in macOS 10.13/iOS 11. You can currently only restore files from iCloud Drive, contacts, calendars/reminders and bookmarks, all from the [Advanced section in iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205018).

WhatsApp messages can be restored from Google Drive if you [turned this feature on](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/20887921/?category=5245251).

Alternatively, if you turned on the device backup for iOS, either to you local Mac/PC or to iCloud, you could do a [full restore](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521?locale=en_AU) to get your data back.

Comment: Don't think the iOS version of WhatsApp is able to backup to Google Drive